# Communication beetwen Windows CE and Windows XP applications

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce, wifi, communication

I have a desktop (XP) application and a CE app (Motorola MC9090) and I want to Scan few Barcodes with Motorola and then send the text to the application on PC using WiFi. I have no idea how to do it - any suggestions? (VB.NET preferred)

Answer (score 2):

Think about it logically, and try simplifying this a little;

If you want to do it over WiFi, you're going to need "something" on the device to scan and send, as well as something on a "server" to receive, such as a webservice; so you actually need to write two things.

A simple option would be to put together a simple ASP.Net webservice for receiving the data (and processing it, dealing with authentication, etc.).

You can then write an application for your CE device that interacts with said webservice and handles the user interaction (most scanners will fake key presses into the control with focus). Bear in mind, that you might also need to cope with situations when the WiFi is out of range.

If you're targetting Windows CE, you cannot do it in Visual Studio 2010 or later (as far as I'm aware), so you may need to get hold of VS 2008 (to maximise your support lifecycle)

Comment: Thank you for your advice but could you be more precise about the web service? PC programming is not what i usually do (usually I write programs for PLC's) but it's a part of the project that i just have to do. I've never learned VB.NET programming except for what i nedded for the project. I found most solutions that i nedded, but i just cant find nothing about this. Names of methods that i have to use would be great!

Comment: Visual Studio comes with templates for creating ASP.Net webservices - that should be a good starting point